# how to append or put List<entity> into GAE memcache programming language Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

**Example :**

```
  Query departQuery = pm.newQuery(Department.class);
  List <Department> departList = List<Department>) departQuery.execute();
```

**may i know how to add the departList(List) into memcache.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JCache](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/usingjcache) for App Engine. Instead of `List`, use a subclass (e.g. `ArrayList`) in order for the `departList` to be `Serializable`, and then you can have:

```
cache.put(yourkey, departList)
```

Comment: thanks for your information. Use ArrayList instead of List got error like as follows. **Error 500 org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.StreamingQueryResult cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList**.